# TwitterService does not use ITwitterService

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I was wondering why there is an ITwitterService interface in TweetSharp because this isn't used by the TwitterService class. I would like to use dependency injection in my application and even all methods of twitter service are virtual, it bothers me a bit that there is an interface I can not use.

Thx.